# Antd Table : How to render table with object in list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, antd

I'm using Antd Table with React. And I want to render table by object in list ***without expandedRowRender***.

my list :

```
dataSource = [
  {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'K.',
    car: [
          {
              brand: 'BMW',
              color: 'white',
          },
          {
              brand: 'Mercedes-benz',
              color: 'red',
          }
    ]
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Emma',
    lastName: 'W.',
    car: [
          {
              brand: 'BMW',
              color: 'black',
          }
    ]
  }
]
```

my code like :

```
<Table
     rowKey={(record, index) => {return index}}
     columns={columns}
     dataSource={dataSource}
/>
```

and expect table like this :
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use render property of your column config:

```
const renderCustomCell= (object) => {
    /** render your custom cell with object properties here */
    const { car } = object;
    return <...>;
};

{
    title: 'column title',
    key: 'column_key',
    render: object => renderCustomCell(object),
}
```